# require lot and inventory reports of products in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am helping someone with an existing rails app. I was wondering how to approach something specific though. I need to require a full lot report (inventory report) that shows the full history of a particular parent lot. Then i want to show the results on a reports/inventory page. I am using sqlite3 in development and mysql2 in production but i am not sure how to go about this?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the app?  What models exist in relation to what you want to accomplish (lot, inventory)?  Is there already a relationship between the two?  What exactly do you need help with?  What's the exact next step you are confused about?

Comment: I have a model for the inventory and existing views. Each item has various details such as weight, price etc. I want to create a full report for all the lots which includes the past history of them.

Comment: There are many ways to get from your point A to point B. We need more information, such as table and column names. We *REALLY* need to see the code you've written to solve this, otherwise it seems like you want us to write it from scratch for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you logging the history? Is it in a related table? In the past, I've used a related "History" table to log creation and updates of records- this provides a nice timeline of events for the related record, and can be called via the relation, ie:

Models:

```
# class whose history you are tracking
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :logs
end

# class where you're storing the history log entries
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :record
end
```

Controller:

```
class RecordController < ApplicationController
    include RecordFactory
    ...
    def create
        if @record.create_new_record(record_params) # calls the factory
            ...
        end
    end
    def update
        if @record.update_existing_record(record_params) # calls the factory
            ...
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

Factories

```
class RecordFactory
    def create_new_record(record_params)
        Record.create!(record_params).tap do |record|
            Log.create(...)
        end
    end

    def update_existing_record(record_params)
        Record.update_attr!(record_params).tap do |record|
            Log.create(...)
        end
    end
end
```

Code to call the relation when displaying:

```
record = Record.last #returns last Record created
record.logs #returns logs for record
```

Comment: Creating logs in the controller is not recommend. Use AR callbacks or something at the model level.

Comment: @sethvargo found this recommending to use a factory object instead of an AR callback, updating my suggestion accordingly... https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/130-activerecord-callbacks-considered-harmful